# pyspark - calculation of partitioned data (created with "append" mode) slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I have a performance issue on query after partitioning.

I have a daily parquet file of around 30 millions rows and 20 columns. For example, the file `data_20210721.parquet` looks like:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
| reference |      date_from      |       date_to       |  daytime   | ... |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
| A         | 2021-07-21 17:30:25 | 2021-07-22 02:21:57 | 2021-07-22 | ... |
| A         | 2021-07-21 12:10:10 | 2021-07-21 13:00:00 | 2021-07-21 | ... |
| A         | ...                 | ...                 | ...        | ... |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
```

We have a code to process it to have only a single day and cut a midnight such that we have:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
| reference |      date_from      |       date_to       |  daytime   | ... |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
| A         | 2021-07-21 17:30:25 | 2021-07-22 00:00:00 | 2021-07-21 | ... | <- split at midnight + daytime update
| A         | 2021-07-22 00:00:00 | 2021-07-22 02:21:57 | 2021-07-22 | ... | <- residual
| A         | 2021-07-21 12:10:10 | 2021-07-21 13:00:00 | 2021-07-21 | ... |
| A         | ...                 | ...                 | ...        | ... |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----+
```

The line **2**, can be called a residual because it is not from the same day as the file.

Then we wanted to generate 1 parquet per daytime so the default solution was to process each file and save the dataframe with:

```py
df.write.partitionBy(["id", "daytime"]).mode("append").parquet("hdfs/path")
```

The mode is set to **append** because the next day, we may have residuals from past / future days.

There is also other levels of partitioning such as:

- ID : it is fixed for around a year (quite good to save so storage ;) )
- weeknumber
- country

Even if partition are quite "balanced" in term of rows, the processing time becames incredibly slow.

For example, to count the number of rows per day for a given set of date:

- Original df (7s seconds):

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/data_2021071[0-5].parquet")\
.groupBy("DayTime")\
.count()\
.show()
```

- Partitioned data (several minutes)

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/data")\
.filter( (col("DayTime") >= "2021-07-10") & (col("DayTime") <= "2021-07-15") )\
.groupBy("DayTime")\
.count()\
.show()
```

We thought that there is too many small partitions at the final level (because of the append, there is around 600 very small files of few Kb/Mb) so we tried to coalesce them for each partition and there is no improvements. We also tried to partition only on `daytime` (in case having to many level of partition creates issues).

Is there is any solutions to improve the performance (or understand where is the bottleneck) ?
Can it be linked to the fact that we are partitioning a `date` column ? I saw a lot of example with partition by year/month/day for example which are 3 integers but does not fit our need.

This solution was perfect to solve a lot of problems we had but the loss of performance if far too important to be kept as is. Any suggestion is welcome :)

## EDIT 1 :

The issues come from the fact the the plan is not the same between:

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/data/DayTime=2021-07-10")
```

and

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/data/").filter(col("DayTime")=="2021-07-10")
```

Here is the plan for a small example where `DayTime` has been converted to a "long" as I thought maybe the slowness was due to the datatype:

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/test/").filter(col("ts") == 20200103).explain(extended=True)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('ts = 20200103)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Relation[date_from#4297,date_to#4298, ....] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
date_from: timestamp, date_to: timestamp, ts: int, ....
Filter (ts#4308 = 20200103)
+- Relation[date_from#4297,date_to#4298,ts#4308, ....] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(ts#4308) && (ts#4308 = 20200103))
+- Relation[date_from#4297,date_to#4298,ts#4308, ....] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan parquet [date_from#4297,date_to#4298,ts#4308, ....] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://.../test_perf], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(ts#4308), (ts#4308 = 20200103)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<date_from:timestamp,date_to:timestamp, ....
```

vs

```py
spark.read.parquet("path/to/test/ts=20200103").explain(extended=True)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Relation[date_from#2086,date_to#2087, ....] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
date_from: timestamp, date_to: timestamp,, ....] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Relation[date_from#2086,date_to#2087, ....] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) FileScan parquet [date_from#2086,date_to#2087, .....] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://.../test_perf/ts=20200103], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<date_from:timestamp,date_to:timestamp, ....
```

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your `filter` is actually utilising the partitioned structure, pruning at disk level rather than bringing all data into memory and then applying filter.

Try to check your physical plan

```
spark.read.parquet("path/to/data")\
.filter( (col("DayTime") >= "2021-07-10") & (col("DayTime") <= "2021-07-15") )
.explain()
```

It should have a stage similar to `PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(DayTime#123), (DayTime#76 = your condition)],`

My guess is in your case, it is not utilising this `PartitionFilters` and whole data is scanned.

I would suggest to try experimenting your syntax / repartition strategy using a small data set until you achieve `PartitionFilters`.

Comment: You are right, I tried on 1 week only and the optimized plan are not identical. It is something to activate somewhere on spark (I don't have the exact version but it is 2.X ) ?

Comment: No, there is no extra step to activate and it ispresent in 2.x. Might be an issue with the syntax or the way of giving condition. Just try with a simple `===` to check if it's picking up.

Comment: `===` is not valid for pyspark. I've done some trials that I'll add in an edit of the question.